# Set visible background picture to a docx document with docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I tried BackgroundImage.java sample from docx4j github repository, 
but the result is a blank document with a paragraph containing lines "to see your background, go to 'web layout' or 'full screen reading' document view.

I need the resulting document to be the same like in the next use case in Word 2016:

```
> New blank document - > Design - > Page color - > Fill effects - >
> Picture tab - > Select picture
```

The resulting document has the background picture visible.
Can I do it with docx4j ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see now https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/0fa7220c49a6c3c8c19e9aedde340b933f21ea5a

The missing ingredient was the <w:displayBackgroundShape/> setting